# Stack several px.timeline in one html file

Tags: python, plotly, gantt-chart

So I have a pandas `DataFrame` that I want to visualize as several Gantt charts using `plotly` (about 60 charts to be precise) and export them as an html file. The problem is that I need colors to be unique in each subplot (but they can be duplicated across all subplots).

The default way of creating subplots with `px.timeline`, i.e. `facet_row` argument doesn't seem to allow it. Of course I can assign color to all unique entries in `DataFrame`'s column corresponding to color, but with high number of unique elements the visualization becomes messy:
[image]
Though it is not visible in the screenshot, some colors on other subplots are barely distinguishable.

The alternative way of doing it is to create its own `px.timeline` figure for each part of `DataFrame` and concatenate them like so:

```
with open(filepath, 'w') as dashboard:
    dashboard.write("<html><head></head><body>" + "\n")
    for fig in figs:
        inner_html = fig.to_html().split('<body>')[1].split('</body>')[0]
        dashboard.write(inner_html)
    dashboard.write("</body></html>" + "\n")
```

[image]
The issue with this approach is that resulting file takes up to 50 times more space (200 MB vs 4 MB). Is there any right way to stack all those figures efficiently and avoid memory overhead?

Comment: how large is your dataframe? if it's not private data, could you include a sample of it in your question as well as the code you used to produce your chart? i have a feeling that with an appropriate choice of color palette, you can modify your first method so that the colors are distinguishable